# Recover my data from an encrypted luks disk, error while analyse

Tags: partitioning, mount, encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I tried to encrypt my external hard disk with LUKS but the disk header is buggy.
So I followed the method described here

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281349/mount-error-when-automounting-a-luks-encrypted-usb-flashdrive

And I get this when I analyse the .dd :

```
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
e2fsck: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open USBimage.dd

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

USBimage.dd contains a crypto_LUKS filesystem
```

I tried with alternate superblock without success.
What should I do?
I just want to copy my data in order to erase the disk after that.
Thanks in advance :D